# How to export text side by side for comparison out of org-mode via (ox-)hugo

Tags: org-mode, hugo

For educational purposes I try to generate a Blog-website via ox-hugo with a two column layout. On the left the philosophical text, on the right annotations.
It is crucial that these textblocks are aligned.

```
xxxxTEXTxxxxx   yANNOTATIONSy
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   yyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxx   yyyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxx   yyyyyyyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   yyyyyyyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxxxxxx   yyyyyyyyyyyyy
                yyyyyyyyyyy

xxxxxxxxxxxxx   yyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

1. I think this might work quite well with [[fn:]] Footnotes, therefore I guess the right template for HUGO would suffice for this?
2. Another possibility might be the »COLUMNS« Environment in Org-mode, but I doubt that alignment could be achieved easily.

   I try to investigate further, I will report back,- I thought this might be useful for others aswell.

Comment: Meanwhile I have found following theme: https://github.com/capnfabs/paperesque 
I will dig into that one and maybe I'll manage to adapt it to my needs.

Comment: See if https://scripter.co/sidenotes-using-ox-hugo/ helps.